# Referencing a variable in an SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have an SSIS package which iterates over a table, and for each row in the table, passes the values from two different columns as parameters to a stored procedure. At least, that's what it is supposed to do. What it actually does is give me this error:

```
[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "EXEC sproc_AccessImport @mAccessLocation (SELECT M..." failed with the following error: "Must declare the scalar variable "@mAccessLocation".". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
```

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1437/dynamically-build-connection-objects-for-ms-access-databases-in-ssis/) in order to make the part that grabs the info, and the code that is supposed to execute the stored procedure is:

```
EXEC sproc_AccessImport @mAccessLocation (SELECT MVID FROM tbl_AccessMailDataFiles WHERE FileLocation = @mAccessLocation)
```

I've been looking around online, but haven't found anything useful. This is the first time I've used SSIS, so I suspect I'm simply doing something wrong. Does anyone know what exactly that is? Thanks.

Edit: I tried mapping the variable as a parameter, with the options:

```
Variable Name:  User::mAccessLocation
Direction:      Input
Data Type:      VARCHAR
Parameter Name: Path
Parameter Size: 200
```

And changed the SQL query to:

```
EXEC sproc_AccessImport @Path (SELECT MVID FROM tbl_AccessMailDataFiles WHERE FileLocation = @Path)
```

It now gives me the error:

```
[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "EXEC sproc_AccessImport @Path (SELECT MVID FROM tb..." failed with the following error: "Must declare the scalar variable "@Path".". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
```

So, really, the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how your package is set up you may need to map the SSIS variables to the parameters within the Execute SQL Task. the specific error you are seeing is most liklely because you are using an OLEDB connection and the statment should probably read

```
EXEC sproc_AccessImport ? (SELECT MVID FROM tbl_AccessMailDataFiles WHERE FileLocation = ?)
```

If you are following the example you linked to then you would map the User::mAccessLocation to the first and second parameter. I hope that makes sense, but I'm not 100% on how you have this set up.

Comment: I edited my answer with a response, because it was easier than trying to put it in a comment. If there's any other information that would help, let me know. I'm not sure what all will be helpful.

Comment: Even though you are declaring a name in the properties of the Execute SQL Task the paramter should still be represented by a ? for an OLEDB connection.

Comment: Ah, okay. That's odd. Well, now it's saying `[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "EXEC sproc_AccessImport ? (SELECT MVID FROM tbl_Ac..." failed with the following error: "No value given for one or more required parameters.".` That sounds like it may be a problem with it grabbing the data, though.

Comment: You'll also want to use a number for the paramter name. You can see how to set up here: [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140355.aspx) Since you are using the same parameter twice you'll need to map two parameters (0 and 1 as the names), but use the same variable.

Comment: Oh, now I see! That makes sense. Alright, that seems to have fixed it, now it's just complaining that I'm not passing a second parameter to the sproc. Is this something wrong about this? `EXEC sproc_AccessImport ? (SELECT MVID FROM tbl_AccessMailDataFiles WHERE FileLocation = ?)` It should be passing the variable as the first parameter, and the selected MVID as the second parameter.

Comment: I don't think the subselect will work as a paramter. (I can't get that to work either). My take would be to create a new SSIS variable for the MVID and grab that in the initial query.     'Select FileLocation,MVID From dbo.AccessDataFiles'    you can then just pass this is the second paramter.

Comment: Alright, that works. Now I'm getting `[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "EXEC sproc_AccessImport ? ?" failed with the following error: "An error occurred while extracting the result into a variable of type (DBTYPE_STR)".` This string of cascading errors seems to be about par for the course when I'm trying to use SSIS.